# hibernate - query return type

Tags: hibernate, mapping, hibernate-mapping

I have a (relatively) simple HQL query that returns two joined entities, that have a one-to-many relation.
As a result of the query, I want to obtain a list of type entity1, where entity1.entity2 is mapped.
Because I get a cartesian product in the result set, where for every entity2 (the many side) I have 1 row, I get duplicates of entity1.
Thus, if I list() the result, I get duplicate entries.

To resolve this problem, I use `query.setResultTransformer( Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY );`

However, this does not always return a list of rntity1, but sometimes a list of entity2.

Is there a way to specify the "main" entity of the ResultSet?

Comment: 'SELECT msg FROM com.intelerad.hibernate.spike.models.Messages AS msg  LEFT JOIN feetch msg.commands AS cmd  WITH ( lower( cmd.status ) = \'failed\' )' gives a "with-clause not allowed on fetched associations;"

Comment: 'SELECT msg, cmd FROM Messages AS msg  LEFT JOIN msg.commands AS cmd  WITH ( lower( cmd.status ) = failed )'  returns the wrong root entity (commands instead of messages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second query is asking to return both Messages and Commands, so that's why you get both types of objects. Just have it return msg.

You should be able to move the desired WITH into the WHERE clause

```
SELECT msg FROM Messages AS msg LEFT JOIN FETCH msg.commands AS cmd WHERE( lower( cmd.status ) = 'failed' )
```

Comment: that's not what I'm trying to get. there is a significant difference between "LEFT JOIN FETCH msg.commands ON lower( cmd.status ) = 'failed'" and "LEFT JOIN FETCH msg.commands WHERE lower( cmd.status ) = 'failed'"
In my case, the first one will return a subset of messages, only the ones whose sendCommands have failed, while the other one will return ALL messages, with only a subset of the sendCommands

Comment: I've done the LEFT JOIN ON clause1 AND clause2 in SQL and it worked - I just need it in HQL

Comment: This is one of those things I know I've been able to achieve with HQL in the past, and it's escaping me at the moment how I did it. I'll have to noodle on it for a bit.

Comment: You can't do LEFT JOIN FETCH WITH in HQL because Hibernate wants the collection to match the database. It's either fully populated or not fetched at all. I can't test this now but didn't the error you got suggest trying a filter?